# What is the value initialized with "date" parameter in date-picker's beforeShowDay function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

What is the value initialized with "date" parameter of function on `beforeShowDay`?

```
$('#selector').datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
         if (date == myDate) {
          return [true, 'css-class-to-highlight', 'tooltipText'];

          }
       }
});
```

What is the starting and ending value of date parameter in `beforeShowDay`?

Is it taking based on current date or `minDate`, `maxDate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `beforeShowDay` is called for each day showed in the calendar... so in a month view... the method is called for each date in the month.

You can just log the value of `date` in the callback to see how it is called

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#selector').datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            console.log(date);
            return [true];
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/u5ybnub8/1/)

Comment: Assume my mindate = "05/01/2014" and maxDate = "21/08/2014" what will be the values of date?

Comment: @RajavelD [see this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/u5ybnub8/2/)... it is called from date  `27/07/2014` to `06/09/2014` when you view the month `Aug 2014`

Comment: in you fiddle shows that at beginning date start from 26 july, how it was taken, in this case if i want to highlight before that dates how its possible?

Comment: @RajavelD if you open your windows calendar for the month of `Aug 2014` it will display from `27/07/2014` to `06/09/2014`... it is a similar logic used here

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, Now i understood, actually i was problem with comparing the date. Now its working fine, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Date parameter value will be set as per the selection of date
```

But function will be called before display the date